# Cannot get correct behaviour in batch loop

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I am using the following loop in a batch file to individually call 'functions' in the file starting by displaying text and finishing with an errorlevel check and display.

Calling the loop function uses 2 variables..

1. the sub function name to be called
2. the text to echo on screen for user ease

This is what those calling lines look like

```
call :loop BackupDatabase "Taking database backup"
call :loop StopBGService "Stopping the background service"
```

This is the loop function itself

```
:loop
    :retry
    echo %~2
    call :%~1

    IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
        SET ERRORLEV=%ERRORLEVEL%
        ECHO Executing %~2 failed
        ECHO Error Level: %ERRORLEV%
        ECHO.

        set /p ans=Do you want to retry %~2 [y/n]^>
        if "%ans%"== "y" goto :retry
        if "%ans%"== "Y" goto :retry
    )
GOTO :EOF
```

Below you would find the functions that are called by each loop

```
:BackupDatabase
    Perform database backup commands
GOTO :EOF

:StopBGService
    Perform stop background service commands
GOTO :EOF
```

The problem I am having is when a "loop" goes wrong the script should ask if a retry is required, the very first time this happens, if you enter "n" it still retries? I've read over the loop script over and over and can't tell why this is. If anyone can fix this it would be a great help, or if someone can point out a better way of doing what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Did you try using `choice` instead of `set`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the Windows Command Prompt / Command-Line Interpreter (CLI),
known as CMD.EXE, has a bug (well, I’m sure Microsoft thinks that it’s a feature) wherein,
when it reads a block construct like `IF … ( … )` or a `FOR` loop,
it interprets all `%variable_name%` variables *immediately*, before the loop is executed. 
In your example, if `ans` is null when you enter the `IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ( … )` block,
then all occurrences of `%ans%` inside that block evaluate to null,
even if you change `ans` inside the block. 
You can see this if you leave `ECHO` on (or turn it back on just before `IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0`).

The fix is to tell CMD to allow variables to be expanded at the right time,
when the statements referring to them are executed.  You do this by adding

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
```

somewhere near the beginning of your batch file, and changing your user-dialog code to look like

```
    set /p ans=Do you want to retry %~2 [y/n]^>
    if "!ans!" == "y" goto :retry
    if "!ans!" == "Y" goto :retry
```

using the `!variable_name!` form to activate the delayed expansion. 
See `SET /?` and `SETLOCAL /?` for more information.

Comment: That's perfect, thanks Scott. Could you see any reason why not to include setlocal enabledelayedexpansion by default to all my batch scripts, and then use the !variable_name! notation when required?

Comment: Hmm.  I vaguely recall having a batch file once that needed delayedexpansion turned off, but it was doing something unusual.  It’s probably a pretty good idea to turn it on all the time.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be causing me any problems, so I'll leave it off in this script or any others that require it to correctly use the FOR loop. If I were to have a script where it would cause an issue I would switch it off before the FOR loop and back on again after the FOR loop.

Comment: @GhandiManning: Be careful of that.  Did you look at `SETLOCAL /?`? You “switch off” a `SETLOCAL` by saying `ENDLOCAL` –– and that erases any variables that you set since the `SETLOCAL`, puts you back in the directory you were in before the `SETLOCAL`, and maybe some other things.

Comment: Thanks, I will bare that in mind. As it stands the script doesn't require `ENDLOCAL` so I won't encounter those problems.